# Please tell me how to run bedwars on the wii-u

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, wii-u

My son and friend want to play bedwars on the wii-u. Do I need to register with a server that runs bedwars in order to access it via the wiiu minecraft menu? I am a noob in this field, so please any hints gratefully accepted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so wii-u appears to be the exception for this fun :-( On the ipad minecraft version is a server tab and you can connect to the "Lifeboat Network" in order to play bedwars.

Answer (score 0):

If you and your son want to take the time and effort and establish rules, your son and his friends could make a bed wars map, me and my siblings made our own homemade bed wars with a working system. Happy crafting!